# How do I examine scope in an Angular directive from within the link function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a fairly simple Angular directive, with its own template. However, if `admin === true`, I want to modify some properties on some of the elements, e.g. to make them `ui-sortable`.

```
app.directive('members',function(){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<h4>{{title}}</h4>'+
  'admin? <span>false</span>' +
        '<ul ng-model="list">' +
        '<li ng-repeat="member in list">' +
        '   {{member.name}}' +
        '</li>'+
        '</ul>',
    transclude:true,
    scope: {title:'@',list:'=',admin:'@'},
    link: function ($scope,$element,attrs) {
  if ($scope.admin) {
        $element.find("span").html("true");
          $element.find("ul").attr("ui-sortable","");
  }
    }

};
})
```

I use the `$element.find("span")` just to test if it is finding it. `admin` is pulled into the isolate scope from the element's attributes, but it still doesn't pass through.

fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/zqM4Z/4/

It appears that the isolate scope is **not** available within the `link` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be a versions issue. The following works for me using version 1.2.0

```
link: function ($scope,$element,attrs) {
    console.log($scope.admin); // gives 'true'
```

Comment: Looks like it is. Earlier versions (not sure which) apparently don't set '@' scope properties until much later. I had to use `attrs.$observer('admin')` which is strange.

Comment: Right you are. Looks like they changed the link phase at some later point. I will switch to 1.2.0

Answer (score 0):

I have found it very useful for debugging purpose to expose scope globally to window.

```
window.scope = scope; // or $scope from controller/run
```

Then you can examine it with developer tools.

Comment: I was able to do so by using debug tools and putting a breakpoint inside the link fn